# Meteor : Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK

Tags: cordova, meteor, gradle

A lot of similar questions have been asked but I can not find this one.

I have a Meteor Hybrid app and I want to make an apk file from that. I am typing `meteor build --server <ec2.IP>:22888` and I get this error : Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

I have tried the following things:

1. I have already updated my Android Studio and downloaded the SDK tools required. I have also checked the `$ANDROID_PATH` and it is set correctly.
2. I have also tried cordova update but error shows that this is not a cordova project.

Can anyone please help me or suggest me on what should I do and how should I proceed?

Comment: Could you add whether you're using Windows, MacOS or another OS?

Comment: Hi I am using mac